# Terminology and notation for generated subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, semigroups-and-monoids, notation

I would like to think about formation of the smallest subgroup (or monoid, or whatever) $H$  of $G$ containing two given subgroups $A$ and $B$ as an operation on subgroups, and I wonder if there is a standard notation for this.  I know, of course, that I could use
$H = \langle A\cup B\rangle$, but I'd rather have a notation along the lines of $H = A \star B$
or something.  Also, I'd like to have a word for this, so I can say something like "apply the **congeneration** operator to $A$ and $B$ to obtain $H$."

Is there standard notation and terminology for this?

Comment: This is the join in the subobject lattice.  I don't think there is any standard notation

Comment: you can write $\langle AB \rangle$

Comment: Does $A \vee B$ have an existing meaning in this context?

Comment: @LSpice  Unfortunately, yes!  This is a homotopy-theoretical context, and $\vee$ will certainly risk confusion with wedge sum.